# How to call superclass method in MiniTest

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, minitest

I'm writing a test in `MiniTest` to the app which uses `Devise` and I have a little (I hope) problem.

I want to check if the user's password is correct. There is a method 
`valid_password?(password)` called on a particular user which does what I need.

But my problem is that in this app this method is overwritten in that way:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  if condition
    # some else code 
  else 
    super
  end
end
```

Is there any possibility to use `valid_password`? from `super` (Devise) in the unit tests?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some "hacky" ways that you could achieve this, but the **right**™ way to do this is to structure your test such that `condition` is falsey. The way to do this, of course, depends on how `condition` is defined!

*For example*, suppose the method is implemented as:

```
def condition(password)
  password.length < 10
end
```

In that case, you should simply run the test with a long password.

You *could* also (as a last resort) stub the `condition` method to return false - but this is bad practice. Your test would then not be a reflection of reality, since the actual circumstances under which `super` is being executed may not be fulfilled.